# Wpf DataGrid hide complete row through DataBinding

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Is there a possiblity to hide DataGrid-rows through DataBinding:
If I have items of a BO or a ViewModel that have a visibilty-property, is there a possibility to declare a binding so that the row will be hidden if the property is set to invisible and vice versa?

Comment: If it is all bound why not simply remove the model data in the backing collection so that row is "hidden" and add the model data back in to make it "visible"?

Comment: @Aaron: Sadly I dont can change the content of the source-collections.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It should be possible to do it via `RowStyle`. Something like this:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Visibility}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I might add that your binding property must output the string "Collapsed" for the row to be collapsed (not a boolean value).

Comment: Can someone detail what the other side of this would look like in the code? How would you toggle the visibility in C#?

Comment: @crclayton Johnc clearly explains that the "binding property must output the string 'Collapsed"'". In case it's not clear, the "binding property" is `Visibility`.