# Unable to bind the data dynamically in multi column Listview in WPF (VS2010)

Tags: wpf

My Xaml is:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listViewResult" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="gridResult">
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Server" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Value"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Availability"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Status"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

And C# code is:

```
listViewResult.Items.Clear();      

listViewResult.Items.Add(new { Server = "test1", Value = "ABX", Availability = "Yes", Status = "No"});
```

But the value is not getting display in Multi Column Listview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you haven't specified anywhere what to display. You can either specify a GridViewColumn.CellTemplate or simply use `DisplayMemberBinding` to specify what property of the data object you want to display:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listViewResult" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="gridResult">
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Server" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Server}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Availability" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Availability}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Oh, sure, answer it while I'm answering it... :)

Comment: I need one more help fron you.How can i change the Row background color on the basis of perticular condition??

Comment: See my answer here on how to customize a row: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728561/wpf-datagrid-hide-complete-row-through-databinding/4728719#4728719. Basically you should define a style for your row and using DataTrigger change the background of it basing on your condition.

Answer (score 2):

The Header is just what shows up as the column heading.  If all you want is the text associated with the data, you need to add a DisplayMemberBinding to actually put data in the column.

```
<ListView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           Name="listViewResult" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="gridResult">
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" 
                                    Header="Server" 
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Server}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" 
                                    Header="Value"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" 
                                    Header="Availability"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Availability}"/> 
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" 
                                    Header="Status"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

The alternative is to create a CellTemplate with a DataTemplate, if you want more control over the appearance.  For example:

```
       <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Status" />
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2,4">
                        <Image Source="Resources\SomePicture.ico" 
                               Height="24" 
                               Width="24" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" 
                                   Margin="2, 4" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
```